# Write numbers using stream writer on the same line in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Below code gives **OUTPUT1** as mentioned below.How can I achieve **OUTPUT2**.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("testdata.txt", true))
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1500; i++)
    {                        
        writer.WriteLine(i +","); //OR  writer.Write(i + ",");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT1** :

```
1,
2,
3,
```

**OUTPUT2**:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: Where do the commas come from? is the code you're showing here the actual code you're using?

Comment: I'm guessing the commas are added by the invisible `writer.WriteLine(",");`

Comment: You've just edited the answer out of your own question... what is the *actual* code you're using? `Writeline` with a lowercase `l` isn't a valid method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *do* need to use `.Write` instead of `.WriteLine` but what I'm guessing you're seeing is the result of

```
new StreamWriter("testdata.txt", true)
```

The `true` means it *appends* to the file, since you've probably ran this code with `WriteLine` previously, you can probably scroll past the first 1500 lines to find your code all on one line

Answer (score 5):

Use `writer.Write` instead of `writer.Writeline` to avoid extra line breaks.

Comment: with writer.Write I do get the new line  which I dont want

Comment: @Raulp `Write` method doesn't inserts anything except string provided to it. `WriteLine` inserts extra line break after this string. So where exactly you're getting unwanted newline? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Raulp - please post some code that a) You have run, b) Only contains `Write` calls rather than `WriteLine` and c) Produces these extra lines you claim. At the moment, we're having to guess at what code you're actually running and it either is *trivially* solvable by not calling `WriteLine` or it doesn't exhibit the problem you claim.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Write() function because WriteLine() function is wrote then jump the line like "1\n 2\n 3\n".

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("testdata.txt", true))
            {

                for (int i = 1; i <= 1500; i++)
                {
                    writer.Write(i +",");
                }
            }
```